# Performing an operation on all members of a structure

Tags: vb.net, structure, basic

I have the following structure:

```
Structure StruRentalItem
    <VBFixedString(4)> Public ItemID As String
    <VBFixedString(20)> Public Name As String
    <VBFixedString(30)> Public Description As String
    <VBFixedString(10)> Public PricePerDay As String
    <VBFixedString(4)> Public QuantityAvailable As String
End Structure
```

I use this for reading records from files but this leaves trailing spaces in all members of the structure because I am using fixed-length records.

How could I perform the .Trim function on all members of the structure.

Comment: [Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct)  also serialization would be much easier than fixed length random access files

Comment: You could use reflection to enumerate the fields, data.GetType().GetFields().  But you have to make it a Class since you need to use FieldInfo.SetValue() to modify the field values.

Comment: Clean the data before you place it in the structure?

Comment: Create a method named trim. In the method, trim all fields. Honestly more effort than that is wasted, right?